# How to build up a va_list in c++

Tags: c++, printf, variadic-functions

I have an argument struct with different types and values (this is not that important to my question):

```
enum class ArgType {...}

struct Argument
{
    ArgType type;
    void* value;
}
```

I have a custom dynamic `List` implementation that I use to create a list of `Argument`s. I then have the following function which can take in this list and my aim is to loop through this list and build a `va_list`:

```
void foo(List<Argument>* args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < args->length; i++)
    {
        Argument* arg = args->get(i);
        char* value = (char*) value;
        // build a `va_list` from value
    }
}
```

I then have a function called `bar` which will build a va_list using the `foo` function, and will print a formatted string.

```
void bar(char* format_str, List<Argument>* args)
{
    // get va_list from: foo(args);
    vfprintf(stdout, format_str, argptr);
}
```

How would I build a `va_list`, or make something like a `va_list` that I can still pass to `vfprintf`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't really waste your time on obsolete C legacy baggage like va_list. Instead, you should focus your efforts on learning C++11 and later, where variadic template parameters and parameter packs provide a superior, type-safe replacement for va_list, and friends.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing std::vector<int> items to variadic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276902/passing-stdvectorint-items-to-variadic-function)

Comment: This will depend on your compiler; there is no standardized way to do this.

Comment: OT: `List<Argument>* args` a pointer? Use a reference in C++.

Comment: Please consider sending output to [`std::cout, std::wcout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) rather than `stdout`.  Iterate through your `List<Argument>` and let this do the work for you.

If you need a string first for some reason, then explore the use of [`std::basic_stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) (i.e., an appropriate specialization thereof).

These (by design) will simplify your life tremendously.

Comment: You should prefer smart pointers, perhaps [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Comment: @manni66 I don't see any reason not to use pointers, and i can change the address of the pointer to a new object.

Comment: Is there any difference between std::cout and stdout? Yes, I could do that, but building up a string is probably a better idea.

Comment: @DavidCallanan Google for "difference between stdout and cout" and you'll get lots of good info to answer that question.

Answer (score 1):

`va_list` is just a pointer to arguments that have been pushed onto the call stack for use with a function `CALL` instruction. Your linked list exists elsewhere in memory. The only way to do what you are asking for is to write assembly code that enumerates the list and pushs the values into the call stack manually. Don't do it, it is highly compiler-dependant and even platform-dependant.

You shouldn't even be using `printf`-style functions in C++ to begin with. Use I/O streams instead, like `std::cout`, `std::ostringstream`, etc. Write an `operator<<` for `Argument` and then use a normal loop to enumerate the list and write its values to your desired `std::ostream` object.

In the case of your `bar()` function, you could simply split the `format_str` into a list of tokens, and then write each token to a `std::ostream`, substituting `Argument` values for "special" tokens as needed.

Or, you could just get rid of `bar()` altogether and let the caller directly format its `Arguments` list using whatever `std::ostream` it wants.

Comment: On recent ABIs arguments are not always pushed on the stack

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch perhaps in x64, some arguments are in registers and the rest are on the call stack. But in x86, only `__cdecl` allows variadic arguments, and all `__cdecl` arguments are on the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer, in C++11 or better, using [variadic template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template)s when possible. Read about [parameter pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)s. Consider using [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)-s, [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)-s etc.

If you really want to build a variadic call at runtime (but that is generally a bad idea) you might consider using the [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) (which knows about your particular [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) & [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), and has some bits of assembler).

Today, `va_list` requires compiler support (thru `__builtin_va_start` etc...) and your ABI knows about it (since many calling conventions involve [processor registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register)). See [stdarg(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html) (and notice its `va_copy`) and [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/249941/40065).